# How to determine request language? (no request)

Tags: python, json, http, python-requests, xmlhttprequest

I have a problem. Some popular company has an API. If I do request from python3.4 or other langs. (s.a JS, Postman, cURL) everything is ok. But if I do request from python >= 3.5 - response JSON is wrong. It's not the "Headers" problem, because all of the headers and ordering of headers are the same. I create own Node.js server to determine all of request info. Request from 3.4 and from >=3.5 are the same.

What is it??? How can API determine that the request is made from python >= 3.5 and change the JSON response?

You can see for yourself:

```py
# python version >= 3.5
import requests

url = {
    'url': 'https://apiauto.ru/1.0/offer/cars/1105235269-6558d30b',
    'headers': {
        'x-authorization': 'Vertis ios-62ca2575df9c74b3958d118afcbb7602',
    }
}

r = requests.get(**url)
print(r.json().get('offer').get('state').get('mileage'))
# It must be 170000, but it's 199000... (WTF!)
```

Just do the same request from python 3.4 or Postman or from JavaScript. The mileage will be **170000**. And the 170000 mileage is the right mileage

Comment: Not able to reproduce this behaviour. I get 170000 with python > 3.4

Comment: @buran Yes its true. But if u switch python to >= 3.5. The mileage will be 199000

Comment: I tried with 3.7 and it's 170000. And by the way >3.4 is same as >=3.5

Comment: @buran Hmm... What is your python full-version? And requests version?

Comment: I tried with python 3.7.3 and requests 2.21 and 2.26(latest version). I really don't see how this could affect the response you get.

Comment: @buran I am from Russia. The only way why the response is different, I think is the location. Hmmm.... FYI I do a lot of stuff: default python, docker python, other Russian IP, other Russian PC, system...